# mysql: subtract multiple columns inside the query or out in php?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

which has the best performance? Thanks!

1) `SELECT field01 - (field02 + field03) as estoque FROM table`

2) `$estoque = $rs['field01'] - ($rs['field02'] + $rs['field03'])`

Comment: This is almost certainly dependent on lots of factors that change from one installation to the next.

Comment: impossible to tell, with any degree of certainty. Try both, and check which is fastest. Not that it matters, though, because you won't really _notice_ a difference of .01 of a microsecond anyway. then there's the issue of: what engine are you using, what does the rest of the query look like, and how are you querying? what does you r PHP code look like? It should be near-perferct if you're down to micro-optimizations like this :-P

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question and it would depend on a few considerations,
For most general use, the times would be negligible. SQL code would be faster when math operations have to be done repeatedly to large datasets, and for processing data and adding it back into the database. Part of this involves the fact that large datasets dont need to be transferred to the application/application memory. MySQL i optimized to process data on the db like this, other db's have procedures, etc.
Operations that involve storing the results for further processing, and that need to be really dynamic would be best in PHP code, things such as integrals, fatorials, amortization tables etc.
The caveat to SQL code is that its sometimes more complex than just using PHP, and unless you're beyond needing to process tens of thousands of rows, you probably wont see any speed gains

Comment: I'm not convinced that questions whose answers can be tested as fast as the question can be asked are especially 'good'. Good answer though.